Manga where protagonist has blue/gray hair and is stuck in a dungeon
Every time he dies, he wakes up back in room 1 but the interactions he has with people change. Furthermore, players in the dungeon collect souls from dead beings to upgrade their skills or buy weapons. (I forgot to mention that everyone has unique skills). I remember that he chooses to utilize lightning in later chapters.

Does he retain his level/skills when he goes back? Are other people aware of the loop? Is this set in a medieval fantasy world? Modern world with tower? Is he an isekai insert? Does he know why he is looping?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Is the protagonist the only one who resets, or do others reset as well?

No, everyone, including him, has to restart everything. However, unlike a typical time loop, there are different outcomes to key events.

@DavidW I read this on mangakalot.... Around a year ago?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

@LogicDictates mostly full color

Is he stuck inside the whole time, or are there scenes that take place on the outisde?

@LogicDictates stuck inside the whole time

[L.A.G] (AKA Infinite passive skills)


L.A.G, an unknown space where humans use
abilities or skills through awakening, monsters appear on each floor and room, and missions are given accordingly. The goal here is to reach the bottom. The protagonist repeats death and life countless times in the unknown space L.A.G. However, in this life, he has the ability to own unlimited passive skills and finally has a chance to escape there. However, unlike what he has been through so far, he will not know an inch of the future as L.A.G continues to change. This is a desperate survival story in which no one can be trusted and continues to survive the hellish L.A.G, where there is no end in sight, and fights for escape from the bottom…

I can't even call it a guess. It's this manhwa 100%.
